# iOS TextField view glides out of layout

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, textfield

I'm using TextField in my app. I made it to wrap the content. 
The problem is when the user types a long text the TextField edges glides out of the layout and make some of the view invisible.
is there a way to disable it to expend when it reaches to the layout edges?[image: as you can't see the text glides out of the textfield and the clear button does too]

Comment: Show the code that you already have

Comment: can you provide a screenshot please

Comment: Theres no code yet just the textfield. I have edited and uploaded a screenshot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best thing to do is to change your `UITextField` to a `UITextView`. Here's a function that I like to use quite a lot for this autoresize technique that you'll see in the likes of Apples iMessage:

```
func containerViewHeight() {
    let size = textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: textView.frame.size.width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
    containerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: size.height + 24)
    self.textView.setContentOffset(.zero, animated: false)
}
```

You'll want to call this function initially inside of your `viewDidLoad`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    self.containerViewHeight()
}
```

As well as that, you'll want to conform to the UITextViewDelegate methods by subclassing it at the top of your file like so:

```
class YourViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate
```

Once you add this **AND** you have used `self.textView.delegate = self` inside of your `viewDidLoad`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    self.textView.delegate = self
}
```

you'll then be able to use the textViewDidChange method for that textView, so the final thing you'll want to add in your class is this:

```
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
    self.containerViewHeight()
}
```

Comment: is that solution keeps the look and feel of the TextField? cause I have really liked it.

Comment: @OfekRegev Yes. They do look the same. The only real difference between a UITextField and UITextView is that a UITextView is a lot more flexible and a UITextField is more ideal for text that will always be on one line, i.e an email

Comment: I'll try that. looks like a good solution but a bit long to implement. I'll keep the question alive to let others post their solutions too. thank's a lot.

Comment: @OfekRegev I totally understand. It does look a little more long winded in the answer than it actually is but if you come across a more efficient way, I'd also love to know.

Answer (score 1):

Your textField probably doesn't have a fixed width.
Just put a width constraint to your textField in your storyboard so it will always have the same width, no matter if the text is too long.

**Edit :** if you want a maximum width, you can add 2 width constraints to your textField. One for minimum width and one for maximum width. This way the width of your textField will vary between 100 and 200, depending on the text it contains.

**Minimum width constraint :**

[image]

**Maximum width constraint :**

[image]

Comment: I don't want a fixed width. more like a max width.